# AngularJS ng-include in direcive link doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I have created a directive with link function that contains an element with `ng-include`. But this element with `ng-include` doesn't work.
Does anyone know why doesn't work?

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {     
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.setAttribute('ng-include', "page2.html'");
            elem.append(div);            
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: do you have an error ? is the path page2.html correct ?

Comment: the path is correct.

Comment: there's an orphan `'` ath the end of `"page2.html'"`

Comment: do you see the div if you try to inspect the element ?

Comment: @ fodman1 
i know,  change this. in "'page2.html'" but still doesn work

Comment: yes i can see the div 
<hello-world>

    <div ng-include="'page2.html'"></div></hello-world>

Comment: Here's a plunkr to play around with: https://plnkr.co/edit/x5dJjBs68vIcTzHCDUuU

Comment: here ist my example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/2yuYESDYCyyb0j8ccMvE?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added didn't compiled it, after compile it is working.

```
app.directive('helloWorld',['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {     
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.setAttribute('ng-include', "'page2.html'");
            elem.append(div);

            $compile(div)(scope);
        }
    };
}])
```

Here is [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wj5aey)

Answer (score 0):

Remove unwanted **single inverted comm**a from `"page2.html'");`  to `"page2.html");`

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {     
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.setAttribute('ng-include', "page2.html");
            elem.append(div);            
        }
    };
});
```

Better to use http://jshint.com/ or http://jslint.com/

Answer (score 0):

here ist my example: plnkr.co/edit/2yuYESDYCyyb0j8ccMvE?p=preview